# Differences between including modules in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, include

I am using a lot of third party modules that I have gathered from other areas and am wondering if there is a big difference between including them like I would a module I wrote myself for the package (simple import statement) and using the setup.py to include it in my installation of python?

Edit:

Say I download xlwt for use with python to output to excel files. should I:

1. run setup.py inside xlwt-0.7.5
2. in code:

> ```
> import xlwt
> ```

OR

1. place xlwt folder within my projects folder
2. then import the packages right from that folder with

> ```
> import sys
> sys.path.append('~xlwt/')
> from xlwt import *
> ```

just trying to determine pros and cons of both.

Comment: Maybe you might consider showing the examples in the question body, so it's clear to all exactly what you mean. This will help you get the best possible answers. Good luck!

Comment: theres generally no difference assuming that the package is ready to be imported (IE it doesnt need to compile C stuff etc)  often times however there are other dependencies that may be stored in different places when you use setup .... if this is about distributing your scripts you should look at bundling packages ...

Comment: jmort253 I edited it so it should be more clear.

Comment: My edit is not displaying properaly apparently. In the second option I am adding the folder to my sys path than importing.

Comment: I would not see much advantage to adding manually in comparison to using the setup.py but certainly some potential problems by not using the setup.py script.

Comment: If my answer helps, please confirm it so that anyone else could find this answer easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros of setup.py way:

1. It's a common method which has been widely accepted. If you tell users to copy your program into some folder instead of executing setup.py, that will be a nightmare for them.
2. Copy means you can put program wherever you like. This may lead to import error or even can'f find this program. In project, it goes against efficiency. Writing setup.py in a normal way is a better idea for program installation and environment sharing.

These are pros so far I've found.